# deploymentProperties not read (websphere)

Tags: websphere

Using websphere 8.5. I am trying to use Monitored Directory deployment and use a deployment properties file using this [guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.was_v8/was/8.0/Administration/WASv8_AppDeploy/player.html)

I have enabled the monitored deploy in the global settings. I have also extracted the properties file using wsadmin and verified that it contains the correct configuration (eg. path to a shared library).

I have put the **myconfig.properties** file in:

```
C:\websphere\myserver\monitoredDeployableApps\deploymentProperties
```

I then drag my application **test-ear-app.ear** (an ear file containing a war file) into:

```
C:\websphere\myserver\monitoredDeployableApps\servers\my_server
```

As a result the app is automatically loaded but the **myconfig.properties** is NOT loaded and hence I need to manually specify the shared library afterwards.

Any ideas why the **myconfig.properties** is not loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you deploy using property file you don't drag ear to monitored directory, but just the property file. So in your case you should just drag `myconfig.properties` to the  `monitoredDeployableApps/deploymentProperties` directory. In your config file you have to define location of your ear by `EarFileLocation=/temp/yourApp.ear` it will be automatically loaded and installed in proper scope defined by the `TargetServer/TargetServer/TargetCluster` properties.

See detailed description in page [Installing enterprise application files by adding properties files to a monitored directory](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/trun_app_install_dragdrop_prop.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5&lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

As I read, I think the procedure is the opposite of what you were currently doing : drop the Ear first and then start the install process with the props file.